# How can I calculate the SNR of a curve that has impulse noise added?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise

I have an issue where I'm not sure how to calulate the SNR of a signal that I have in MATLAB. I have a real-world signal dataset that is a curve shape (a bit like a logarithmic curve) that I import into MATLAB from a .CSV. This is my reference curve. I then add impulse noise to the curve using the alpha stable distribution. This noisy signal is then put through a rolling mean filter. I also smooth a separate instance of the noisy curve using the arithmetic mean. I want to compare the SNR of the curve signal and demonstrate how the filter has improved the noisy signal. How can I do this?

Importing the signals x100

```
cd 'C:blah\blah\'
z_numfiles = 100;
for k = 1:z_numfiles
    myfilename = sprintf('scope_%d.csv', k);
    nometal{k} = xlsread(myfilename, 'C4:C500');
end
```

This is two instances of the "raw" signal capture:

[image]

Adding the impulse noise to the "nometal" signal and increasing the size of the dataset from x100 to x1000:

```
pd1 = makedist('Stable','alpha',0.5,'beta',0,'gam',0.001,'delta',0);
temp = 0;
distr_puls_nometal = cell(1000, 1);
samplesize = 497;
loop_count = 1000;
for n = 1:9
    for j = 1:loop_count
        temp = cell2mat(nometal(n));
        
        for i = 1:samplesize
            a = random(pd1);
            temp(i) = temp(i) + a;
            if temp(i) > 3
                temp(i) = 3;
            elseif temp(i) < 0
                temp(i) = 0;
            end
        end
        distr_puls_nometal{n+j} = temp;
    end
end
```

[image]

Comparing a rolling mean and an arithmetic mean of the noisy "no metal" signal:

[image]

How can I calculate the SNR decrease for the "noisy" signal? How can I caculate the signal improvement by attenuating the noise? I also have a number of other noise distributions but I assume that the process will be the same. Thanks all!

Comment: It would be helpful to show your code for the "moving mean" and "arithmetic mean". The moving mean curve doesn't look very sensible to me. You would almost certainly be better off with some sort of heuristic "mean of questionable parentage" that throws away data that is more than 3 sigma (or some other threshold) from a low pass filtered version of the raw data. And using a proper low pass filter rather than a boxcar average so that you don't get abrupt glitches as bad samples enter and leave.

Comment: Hi @MartinBrown thanks for the comment. I know that the moving mean as shown isn't particularly sensible, but I'm not asking for advice on the methods of filtering. I want to know how to calculate the SNR changes from the raw data capture. Thanks!

Comment: what's the difference between "moving" and "arithmetic"? the terms aren't opposites, they're orthogonal. -- do you think the concept of signal-to-noise ratio applies here? according to text books and internet, how is that usually calculated, ignoring your specific situation for a moment?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz here the moving average uses a single signal, and averages the data points within a window of size n that increments in steps of 1. The arithmetic average uses a window of multiple signals and averages each datapoint over a window of signals of size n and increments in steps of 1.

Comment: Your description of your two moving averages is too vague to make sense of. Please show us the actual code used in the question. As for the way to measure the noise level in the data then estimated_noise = sqrt(sum{ (model[i] - data[i])^2} /(N-1) is probably as good as anything. But IRL with known noisy conditions engineers tend to throw away and ignore any data that is obviously a transient glitch or interference spike (scientists do too sometimes but **much** less often and they work a lot harder to obtain the best possible measurements from the outset).